# How to return an array of routes from a function in a Navigator task?

Tags: php, arrays, function, recursion, return

I am not a programmer by profession and myself learn php. I found the Navigator task template on the Internet (the author of the task writes that it can be solved both by recursion and using the Dijkstra algorithm. But you cannot use static variables). I used recursion. The function considers everything correctly, but does not return the array I need. I supplemented my question with a piece of code that I personally wrote. But something is missing in it for the correct output of an array of arrays.
[Task Navigator](https://3v4l.org/vVLL8)

Function written by me:

```php
function makeOneStep($paths, $pathDone, $time, $point, $target)
    {
        foreach ($paths[$point] as $subPoint => $values) {
            if ($subPoint == $target) {
                $pathDone[] = $subPoint;
                $result = array();
                $result['path'] = $pathDone;
                $result['time'] = $time + $paths[$point][$subPoint]['time'];
                return $result;
            } elseif (!in_array($subPoint, $pathDone)) {
                $newPathDone = $pathDone;
                $newPathDone[] = $subPoint;
                $time += $paths[$point][$subPoint]['time'];
                return makeOneStep($paths, $newPathDone, $time, $subPoint, $target);
            }
        }
    }

    $truePaths[] = makeOneStep($paths, array($startPoint), 0, $startPoint, $endPoint);

    var_dump($truePaths);
```

Output Array Example:

```
$truePaths =>
[0] =>'path'=> {
    [0] => "pet"
    [1] => "chk"
    [2] => "spo"
    ...
    [n] => "nov"}
    'time'=> 43
[1] => 'path'=> {
    [0] => "pet"
    [1] => "gor"
    [2] => "vas"
    ...
    [n] => "nov"}
    'time'=> 28
[2] => 'path'=> {
    [0] => "pet"
    [1] => "gor"
    [2] => "gos"
    ...
    [n] => "nov"}
    'time'=> 105
...
```

Comment: Hey @Mars! Welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to be a lot more specific in what you are asking. If you want people to help you with your problem, ask a particular question about a particular piece of code. Your current post appears to be you asking the internet to help you with a homework problem.

Comment: Good day. Added more information on the task. Help me please. In addition to the Internet, I have no one else to turn to.

Comment: Awesome! That is super helpful in knowing what you're looking for! If I were a PHP buff I would help more. Good Luck!